# How to run popen in Django with Apache?

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file from my web server to s3.

Django 1.7.8  + Python 2.7.8

```
os.popen('aws s3 cp c:\1.txt s3://bucket')
```

The popen runs in my development environment (VS code, debug running ok) not Apache.
It seems to not run at all on product environment, which Apache hosts.

Comment: Why would you do this with `popen`? Why would you use the command-line utility at all? There is a very good Python library for interacting with AWS, called `boto`.

Comment: i think aws cli is on top of boto.

Comment: Yes, so it makes even less sense to try and shell out to call it. Import boto and use the API.

Comment: you mean, if use apache, can't evoke popen?

Comment: I don't mean that, but **why would you**? It makes no sense to even try. Look, you are writing an app in Django, in other words in Python. boto is the Python interface to AWS; why use anything else?

Comment: While I agree wholeheartedly with @DanielRoseman, you've got `asw` instead of `aws` and are missing quotation: `os.popen('aws s3 cp c:\1.txt s3://bucket')` And that's without options and arguments: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: Sorry about typo.
It should be this:   os.popen('aws s3 cp c:\1.txt s3://bucket')

Thank you all for comment. I will try. But anyone know why it doesn't work with apache?